# Redirect to custom DNS

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dns

If I'm hosting my own DNS server, can I use JavaScript to redirect a client browser from a web accessible domain to a non-standard domain name like .cthulu?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, not really sure what your asking.

Comment: Sure @Keith, let's say I'm hosting my own DNS because I want to have 127 deep subdomains or whatever. Let's say I have a root domain .cthulu that doesn't exist in the outside world, but I want it to be discoverable through a search friendly "real" domain. Can I use a redirect of some form to get the user to my .cthulu site from the search indexed landing page?

Comment: `.cthulu that doesn't exist in the outside world`  What do you mean by this, you can only get your users to redirect to page that exists.  IOW: If you can access from the outside world, you can access from the outside world, there is no in-between.  IOW: You can redirect a user to any webpage they have access too.  If a browser can't resolve `mysubdomain.cthulu`, then it will just error on redirect.

Comment: So I cannot "show" the browser how to connect to it, without the user adding my DNS servers?

Answer (score 1):

you can set-up a javascript redirect for sure, however in order to open a domain name, it has to be registered and existing, so it could pull content from the web. The domain itself will be registered in ICANN through a domain registrar, so it could become active. Then it can also be indexed by google bots (if you would like to see it there). If you put a redirect to a domain that it is not existing, the browser will simply show up an error message that it cannot find the content.

One of the options is to set-up a local hosts file to open that domain from your server (to resolve to it's Control Panel IP address) and have that domain with DNS zone there to open some content (index file). Then it will work only from the computer with modified local Hosts file, as it will tell it from which server exactly to look for a site to open. Though that does not seems like what you are planning on doing.

Not sure if there is any way to do it the way you want to without registering the domain first. Hope that helps somehow.

Comment: `to resolve to it's Control Panel IP address` sounds like exactly what I want to do from JS.

Comment: The javascript redirect can be done easily using this for example - window.location = 'https://test.com'  , though I can't really tell on how to get your local server address to that site files.

Comment: Right, that is the missing link in this idea 